# GET request with parameters in OAuth 1.0 Signature in cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, oauth, get

so for some days now i've been struggling with more of a logical issue in performing a GET request.

The problem i am facing is the following:

I want to execute a GET request with cURL in php signed with OAuth 1.0 for a REST Service.

The problem i am facing is related to signature generation. 
When i sent the request with base url e.g. 'https://www.example.com' everything seems to be fine and i get the 1st page of the result set.

When i want to see the 2nd page of the result set i need to sent parameters to the url .e.g 'https://www.example.com?limit=100&page=2' when i try to pass this url into the signature or as an endpoint for the cURL i get a signature failed error.

I dont understand therefor what am i doing wrong since i am normally trying to encode the whole url to appropriate format required for the OAuth 1.0 signature

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I have to encode both url paremeters but also my cURL endpoint had to be the long url (to include the paremeters)

Comment: by long url you mean something like:  http://192.168.1.2/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?limit=100&oauth_consumer_key=LBK8kIAq&oauth_token=DENubDnuNBrhXrc8DXDR&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1534439659&oauth_nonce=TeLS1L&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=5dkOC19KzLaRhHu3txg4%3D&page=2&status=draft      I'm stuck on your same problem.

Comment: ok i was stuck with the '?' on the query... mix credentials and queryParams in the same array, key sort them and compute the base signature an oauth_signature... add all of them to the header, then add the queryParams to the url before the request, as normal with the '?' before the queryParams.

Comment: Same issue.. are you find the solution?